# How to create a card gallery in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to card a list/gallery of Bootstrap Cards that arrange by line, go to next line when line is full.  Something to could be achieve with float-left With equally distributes left right margin.
Not knowing in advance how many cards there will be.

**Here is what have for now**

```
<div class="card-deck mx-2" style="width: 100rem">
    <!-- Cards come here -->
</div>
```

**Card (loop generated)**

```
<div class="card mx-auto text-center">
    <a href="[some url]"><img class="card-img-top" src="[some image]" alt="[some title]"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-[some FontAwesome icon]"></span> <a href="[some url]">[some title]</a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 a {
    color:#000;
    font-size:0.6em;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.card-deck .card{
    max-width:320px;
}
```

Currently they all end up in one single line and their width (not height) is reduced when line is filled.
For simplicity, I'm looking for a design where all card are coded the same.
I guess, maybe I'm missing something about Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Any reason you're not simply using the Grid? A `.card` component by default fills 100% of its parent column unless you use the deck/group/column wrappers.

Comment: I don't know Bootstrap 4 very well yet. Trying to use card for aesthetics ... If I use grid I think need to make some assumpation about the number of items. But I'll check with the grid.

Comment: I checked the grid, it requires assumption on number of columns/items

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approached solution for now. Especially the "centering" is very achieved, or it depends on cases. I guess to perfect it I'll need to write a smarter loop which can adapt each card/row/column etc.

```
<ul>
    <!-- Cards come here -->
</ul>
```

**Card**

```
<div class="card mb-4 mx-3 text-center">
    <a href="[some url]"><img class="card-img-top" src="[some image]" alt="[some title]"></a>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-[some FontAwesome icon]"></span> <a href="[some url]">[some title]</a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:90%;
}

li.card {
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 height:20rem;
 width:320px;
} 

h2 a {
    color:#000;
    font-size:0.6em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation you're fairly new to Bootstrap.  You mentioned needing to make an assumption on the number of columns/items in order to make use of the Bootstrap Grid, but this isn't necessarily true.

When Bootstrap encounters columns that would exceed 12, it simply moves those columns to a new row.  With this in mind we can make use of the margin utilities from Bootstrap 4 and ensure that every column has a bottom margin; creating a grid gallery without any loops or specifying when/where a new row should start.

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card mx-auto text-center">
        <a href="#url"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x350" alt="Sample Title"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title"><span class="fa fa-external-link mr-1"></span><a href="#url">Sample Title</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example I've used `col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3` to add a responsive element to how many items appear per row, and `mb-4` ensures that each column has a bottom margin so that each row has a top/bottom margin similar to the left/right created by the Grid.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Bootstrap 4 and Card. Regarding Bootstrap 3 I know some parts of it, but never needed/wanted to use everything in it.
I see what you mean with the responsive grid, but it's limiting possibilities more than I wish.

Comment: If you wanted something in the style of Pinterest or masonry the card column group might work out.

Comment: Quickly tried .card-group yesterday. The thing is that .card-group manages the width, .card-deck also manages width but differently and stays on one line. In both cases I ended up overriding CSS to try to get the fixed width and behaviour I was looking for. I hope there would some kind of card-deck-wrap-line (I read something that looked like that) I think I'll stick with my approached solution for now.